# Creating custom daily evalutations in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I've been looking for a solution for kindergarten teachers to submit daily student evaluations (different criteria) in Moodle. So far, the closest solution that I've found is the Attendance plugin.

Does anyone know of a plugin that allows the teacher to submit a daily evaluation?

Another option that I'm looking into is Moodle Competency, which can actually fit the need, however, it looks like competency is not cumulative ... if I can find a way to make it cumulative that will be awesome.

For example, one of the competencies we have is "able to read sentences" and the scale is "1 - non-developed", "2- being developed" and "3- fully developed". At any point, the teacher or school admin would like to know how competent the student is. In our case, if this is an indicator that is being responded daily, we should be able to take the average and be able to evaluate the student.

The competency framework (to my understanding) doesn't calculate the average, rather it relies on being rated by the teacher.

Any thoughts where I should continue to look?

Comment: Do you want the student to see the evaluation?

Comment: Not necessarily. The school admin would want to see though.

Answer (score 0):

Attendance could be a great solution to your needs.

It could be hidden to the ones acting like students (I'm not shure if the kindergarden kids be interested in see this, maybe their parents)

Attendance have a full compatibility with course grading.

It could be configured to have diferent percentaje of final grading, so far, you can use one attendance activity for have a registry for their personal clairliness, another to record assessment in math, one more to social assessment and so on.

Finally all users with minimun acces as teacher (or another role you defined: example: school administration, scholar control) Could have facilities to export every grading to spreadsheet.

I've several years using it in a similar way you are asking to.

I hope this helps you.